# how to execute in a sequential way two queries in node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm a beginner in node js.I am working with mySQL database. I have a query, which returns me a dataset, and then I use a for loop to access to each element of this dataset. The problem is that inside the loop I make a new query for each element of dataset, and I don't know exactly why this is not working properly. The second query does not return anything until the for loop is end and I would like it returns a value for each element of previous first dataset. Any helps would be grateful, Thanks a lot.

Cristina Osuna

Here the code:

```
first query: geneModel.getGenesRefPut



second query: geneModel.getGenesRefClass

---------------------------------------
/* GET genes page. */

router.get('/genes', function(req, res, next) {


    var listTotal=[];


    geneModel.getGenesRefPut(function(error, data)

    {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     

            var classgene = '';
            var custom_gene = {};

            if (data[i]['Type_Gene'] == "reference") {

                custom_gene = {Name_Gene: data[i]['Name_Gene'], Alias_Gene: data[i]['Alias_Gene'], Id_Plants: data[i]['Id_Plants'], Type_Gene: data[i]['Type_Gene'], Name_SpeciePl:  data[i]['Name_SpeciePl']};

                var id = data[i]['Id_Genes'];

                geneModel.getGenesRefClass(id, function(error, data2)
                {
                    classgene = data2[0]['Class_Name'];
                    custom_gene['classgene'] = classgene;

                });

                listTotal.push(custom_gene);

            }

        }
        console.log(listTotal);
    });

    res.render('genesDetails', {listTotal: listTotal}); 
});
```

Comment: You should read up on asynchronous programming in JavaScript, specifically how to use Promises or [the async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle situations where you want multiple asynchronous requests to complete before triggering the next bit of application logic.

Comment: Ok, I will try, thanks a lot!!